# Android: why does a swipe kill my app?

Tags: android, gesture

I was trying to make a TextView change when I swipe across the screen. I used GestureDector.OnGestureListener, and just recoded the onFling() methode as follows:

```
@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent motionEvent, MotionEvent motionEvent2, float v, float v2) {
    if (motionEvent.getRawY() < motionEvent2.getRawY()) {
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView)).setText("Next");
    } else if (moveTaskToBack(motionEvent.getRawY() > motionEvent2.getRawY())) {
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView)).setText("Previous");
    }

    return true;
}
```

But in my case, for a weird reason, when I flick left the app just stops (like I pressed the home button).

What could be causing this?

EDIT: if I reopen the app and press the return button (physical), it show "previous", therefore I could can conclude that the swipe works but something happening after setting the TextView is the culprit.

Comment: add your logcat output.

Comment: DOes the given id exist in your view?  The most likely cause would be findVieByID returning null.  But give us your logcat to be sure.

Comment: I've got every log message from everything on my phone, is there some way to filter them down to only the one it gets from the app itself?

Answer (score 0):

```
findViewById(R.id.textView)
```

This will throw an error if the textView R.id.textView is not on the current content view.

Sometimes, with overrides, you will need to do this:

```
return super.onFling(motionEvent, motionEvent2, v, v2);
```

Comment: Technically if I can set findViewById(R.id.textView) once ("next"), I shouldn't be concerned about the fact that is isn't on the current view, but I could be wrong (android noobie). 
Also I can't call super.onFling(), it comes from an interface (OnGestureListener).

Comment: "I shouldn't be concerned about the fact that is isn't on the current view" Well, that really is the problem, it's a silly requirement that the views used in findViewById exists on the current view. Maybe store a variable at the class scope, and in the onCreate method initialise it to (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView) and just operate off that?

Comment: I did what you said but it didn't change. Well the problem should lay elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is awkward. In the else if statement, for some reason, auto-complete probably added the function call:

```
  moveTaskToBack(boolean b)
```

Which moves the stack to the back of the activity stack.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#moveTaskToBack(boolean)